# Logging in Java in 2015 - what does a properly configured environment look like?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, log4j, slf4j, java.util.logging

My Eclipse/Tomcat project is a tangled mess of slf4j, log4j, JULI, logback, etc. As a result my console has an abundance of useless messages from various libraries and it is hard to get the logging output I want from my own code. I've resorted to using `System.out` to get stuff done.

The server deployment environment is in similar bad shape.

What I'm wondering is, where can I find a reference implementation, or checklist, that outlines what a correct configuration of all these logging frameworks is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found I don't like the "Internet wisdom" on this which is exemplified by the diagrams at slf4j.org: it's more complicated than it needs to be, and doesn't address technical debt. Here are my recommendations:

- Get rid of log4j. No modern libraries require it, my app shouldn't either.
- Bridge slf4j to jdk14.
- Bind jcl to jdk14 natively (do not use the jcl-over-slf4j bridge)
- Adopt native jdk14 logging in all new code

This seems to provide the simplest configuration with smallest number of config files and directives and fewest surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any examples, but you should try to use slf4j instead of a mixture of logging frameworks. What you can do is use bridges to slf4j instead of the actual libraries. See [slf4j documentation on bridges](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

There is a slight inconvenience with JUL, but little effort you should be able to control that as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I selected a simplified version of the option at the bottom left, which I will post as a separate answer.